# displaying icon in an input file

Tags: html, css

hello i want to display this icon in the input file as shown in the picture and in front of it i will add file : as label [image]

this is the html code :

```
<div class="custom-file">
    <p> file :</p>
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="validatedCustomFile" required>
    
    <label class="custom-file-label" for="validatedCustomFile"></label>

</div>
```

and the css :

```
.custom-file-input ~ .custom-file-label::after {
    content: "fas fa-paperclip";
    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you have to use unicode with pseudo class to have the icon displayed

for sample for fa-paperclip the unicode is f0c6

```css
.custom-file-input ~ .custom-file-label::after {
    content: "\f0c6";
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="custom-file">
    <p> file :</p>
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="validatedCustomFile" required>
    
    <label class="custom-file-label" for="validatedCustomFile"></label>

</div>
```